# Select and button on same line in Panel

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-button

How can I override these JQM enhancements so I can just be able to have a select menu and a button right next to each other.  All the demos just put an easy big button at the bottom of their Panel example, but I got real content and sometimes it can get quite long.  So I need a back button, I don't want data-dissmissible or the other data- attribute for swiping....(death by data attributes)  ;)

The Fiddle is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/magister/CZW78/)

```
    <div data-role="panel" id="leftPanel" data-display="reveal" data-position="left" data-position-fixed="true" data-swipe-close="true" data-dismissible="true">
    <div data-role="fieldcontain" data-theme="a">
        <select name="selectNavType" id="selectNavType" data-mini="true">
            <option value="TopicsNavView" selected="selected">Topic</option>
            <option value="IndexNavView">Index</option>
            <option value="ToolsNavView" >Tools</option>
        </select>
        <a href="#" data-rel="close" data-role="button" data-icon="carat-l" data-iconpos="notext" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="false" ></a>
    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I fixed it here http://jsfiddle.net/magister/CZW78/1/                  However I would still like the Select to be larger

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean you want a bigger Icon on the select?

if so you can use this css

```
.ui-btn-icon-left:after, .ui-btn-icon-right:after, .ui-btn-icon-top:after, .ui-btn-icon-bottom:after, .ui-btn-icon-notext:after #selectNavType  {
 margin-top:-14px;
 width: 28px;
 height: 28px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

well thanks for the response.  I double checked all the attributes and found 
     data-inline="true"

for both the select and the button

the select was too small after doing this so I found the style associated with it after JQM enhancement

```
  .ui-panel-inner > .ui-field-contain > .ui-select.ui-btn-inline {width:10em;}
```

UPDATED FIDDLE IS [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/magister/CZW78/2/)

Comment: yeah, that looks nice